# Error in tmux's configuration file

Tags: linux, config, tmux

In `.tmux.conf` file, I have this line :

```
set -g status-left '#(iwgetid | cut -d '"' -f 2)'
```

which throws an error when I run `tmux` :

```
/home/user/.tmux.conf:8: invalid or unknown command: set -g status-left '#(iwgetid | cut -d '"' -f 2)'
```

The error is at the `"` because when I change it with a `,` instead, `tmux` doesn't throw an error. Of course, it doesn't behave as expected also.

Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem?

I already tried escaping `"` and `'` without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with what you want the shell to get:

```
iwgetid | cut -d '"' -f 2
```

Wrap it in `#()` so that it will be treated as a shell command in the expansion of `status-left`:

```
#(iwgetid | cut -d '"' -f 2)
```

Embed this as a string that *tmux* can parse. You tried to put single quotes around it:

```
'#(iwgetid | cut -d '"' -f 2)'
```

The problem is that *tmux* will interpret the first of the “inner” single quotes and the first of the “outer” single quotes as a single string segment, leaving the following double quote at the top-level where it now forms an unterminated string segment; the error message is not terribly clear in this situation.

To fix the problem you need to properly quote the format string (which embeds the shell command) for your chosen *tmux* quote characters. You might do it like this:

```
set -g status-left '#(iwgetid | cut -d '"'\"'"' -f 2)'
```

But, that is a bit hard to read, so you might consider switching your shell command to something more easily *tmux*-quotable:

```
iwgetid | cut -d \" -f 2
```

Which you can embed in `status-left` with *tmux* single quotes like this:

```
set -g status-left '#(iwgetid | cut -d \" -f 2)'
```

Or with *tmux* double quotes like this:

```
set -g status-left "#(iwgetid | cut -d \\\" -f 2)"
```

Keep in mind that *tmux* quoting is similar to, but not identical to Bourne-style shell quoting (e.g. top-level backslash escaping does not work the same). This quoting system is used in the config file, `command-prompt` (e.g. Prefix `:`), the `confirm-before` and `if-shell` command parameters, and the command templates for the `choose-` commands.